# I am not able to correctly assign a value to a df row based on 3 conditions (checking values in 3 other columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to assign a proportion value to a column in a specific row inside my df. Each row represents a unique product's sales in a specific month, in a dataframe (called testingAgain) like this:

```
  Month       ProductID(SKU)        Family       Sales       ProporcionVenta
    1         1234                FISH      10000.0              0.0
```

This row represents product 1234's sales during January. (It is an aggregate, so it represents every January in the DB)

Now I am trying to find the proportion of sales of that unique productid-month in relation to the sum of sales of family-month. For example, the family fish has sold 100,000 in month 1, so in this specific case it would be calculated 10,000/100,000 (productid-month-sales/family-month-sales)

I am trying to do so like this:

```
for family in uniqueFamilies:
      for month in months:
        salesFamilyMonth = testingAgain[(testingAgain['Family']==family)&(testingAgain['Month']==month)]['Qty'].sum()
        for sku in uniqueSKU:
          salesSKUMonth = testingAgain[(testingAgain['Family']==family)&(testingAgain['Month']==month)&(testingAgain['SKU']==sku)]['Qty'].sum()
          proporcion = salesSKUMonth/salesFamilyMonth
    
          testingAgain[(testingAgain['SKU']==sku)&(testingAgain['Family']==familia)&(testingAgain['Month']==month)]['ProporcionVenta'] = proporcion
```

The code works, it runs, and I have even individually printed the proportions and calculated them in Excel and they are correct, but the problem is with the last line. As soon as the code finishes running, I print testingAgain and see all proportions listed as 0.0, even though they should have been assigned the new one.

I'm not completely convinced about my approach, but I think it is decent.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in Pandas (even Numpy), unlike general purpose Python, analysts should avoid using `for` loops as there are many vectorized options to run conditional or grouped calculations. In your case, consider [**`groupby().transform()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) which returns inline aggregates (i.e., aggregate values without collapsing rows) or
as docs indicate: *broadcast to match the shape of the input array*.

Currently, your code is attempting to assign a value to a subsetted slice of data frame column that should raise `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Such an operation would not affect original data frame. Your loop can use `.loc` for conditional assignment

```
testingAgain.loc[(testingAgain['SKU']==sku) &
                 (testingAgain['Family']==familia) &
                 (testingAgain['Month']==month), 'ProporcionVenta'] = proporcion
```

However, avoid looping since `transform` works nicely to assign new data frame columns. Also, below `div` is the [Series division](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) method (functionally equivalent to `/` operator).

```
testingAgain['ProporcionVenta'] =  (testingAgain.groupby(['SKU', 'Family', 'Monthh'])['Qty'].transform('sum')
                                                .div(testingAgain.groupby(['Family', 'Month'])['Qty'].transform('sum'))
                                    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your second approach (using transform and div) is so clean and works perfectly. Appreciate it a lot.